# Fatal error using RxTx and xbee

Tags: java, rxtx, xbee

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180008790, pid=6616, tid=2668

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x8790]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 D:\Sens6\Sensacopter6.0\hs_err_pid6616.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I have this fatal error trying to read data from an Xbee usin RxTX Libraries...

when I conect an Arduino I can read from COM that I want, but when I conect the xbee it apears this..

I don't know how to solve..

Comment: There's no way for us to diagnose an access violation on your computer, of a native library of which the version and source are not provided here.

Comment: You'll need to post some of your code, and possibly the output of `hs_err_pid6616.log`.  Consider enabling core dumps so we can see a stack trace of the problem.